# Typescript Splice an Item from an array nested within an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, multidimensional-array

I have an array of items nested within another array of items. Im trying to remove a specific item within the nested array. I have the code below.

```
removeFromOldFeatureGroup() {
for( let i= this.featureGroups.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
  if( this.featureGroups[i].featureGroupId == this.oldFeatureGroupId)
    for( let z= this.featureGroups[i].features.length-1; z>=0; z--) {
      if( this.featureGroups[i].features[z].featureId == this.featureId)
        this.transferedFeature = this.featureGroups[i].features[z];
        this.featureGroups[i].features[z].splice(z, 1);
        return;
    }
}
}
```

When i get to splice, an error is thrown saying splice is not a function. How can this be fixed? Also, this.transferedFeature is the correct one i need to remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
this.featureGroups[i].features.splice(z, 1);
```

As `this.featureGroups[i].features` is the array within the array (based on your description).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mistaking element at z to be an array, this is the correct code

```
removeFromOldFeatureGroup() {
    for( let i= this.featureGroups.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
    if( this.featureGroups[i].featureGroupId == this.oldFeatureGroupId)
        for( let z= this.featureGroups[i].features.length-1; z>=0; z--) {
        if( this.featureGroups[i].features[z].featureId == this.featureId)
            this.transferedFeature = this.featureGroups[i].features[z];
            this.featureGroups[i].features.splice(z, 1);
            return;
        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's all about use of indexing.

```
outerArr = [];
inner= [1,121,13];
outerArr.push(inner);
console.log(outerArr);
outerArr[0].splice(0,1)
console.log(outerArr)
```